# Can't access Microsoft.Xrm namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I've downloaded CRM Dynamics SDK and keep it in a local directory. In my code, I'm using `EntityCollection` (amongst other classes related to Xrm namespace), which means that I need to add `using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;`.

The problem is that during compilation I get errors saying that:

> The type or namespace name 'Xrm' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

So, I double check that the reference is made and, very accurately, I see that `microsoft.xrm.sdk` indeed **is** in my list. Just to be sure, I've removed it and added it again by pointing to the DLL with the same name. To no avail, though... The flabbergasting thing is that my colleague uses the same code and it compiles on his machine (the only difference being that he's on Win 7 and I'm on Win 8).

How do we kill this problem?

Comment: Got this error when moving to CRM 2015 SDK, the problem was that I was not targeting the right framework, ie: .Net 4.5.2 as MS switched this in this latest release. More details here: http://www.syntaxwarriors.com/2015/using-crm-2015-sdk-gives-error-that-xrm-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Double check in your project settings to see which Target Framework you are using. If it is **.NET Framework 4 Client Profile** try changing it to **.NET Framework 4**.

Comment: Just saw it myself. This was annoying error. The default setting should definitely be the full blown .NET 4, not the circumcised version. Thanks anyway. I'll make sure to grade your answer up and do the same to the questions because this kind of thing is good to be able to find easily. Such stuff can drive one insane, when working alone...

Answer (score 23):

I received this when replacing my crm 2013 dlls with the new 2015 ones.

None of the above solutions worked for me. 
But what eventually led me on the right track was this warning (it was listed as a warning below the namespace errors):

> The primary reference "Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=5.0.9689.2166,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built
>   against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher
>   version than the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"

And when I checked I only had .Net 4.5.1 installed so after installing .Net 4.5.2 **Developper pack**  and switching the target framework of my projects to this everything worked again.

The regular 4.5.2 update is not enough to get this version of .net in VS, you need the [developper pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637)

Source: http://www.syntaxwarriors.com/2015/using-crm-2015-sdk-gives-error-that-xrm-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace/

Comment: interesting, I just came across this answer and apparently I have upvoted it in the past. That means past-me had the same problem, solved it by using this post and consequently forgot about it altogether

Answer (score 2):

I had my framework **already set to .NET Framework 4** therefore solution of switching between 4 Client profile and regular 4 did not apply. A trick I did was **changing .NET Framework into 3.5 and then back to 4.0**. I hope this will help some people.

Thx @Jason Lattimer. Your answer gave me a clue how to solve my problem.

**Good luck CRM developers!**

Comment: Doing this did not solve my XRM namespace error but did solve another error. Sometimes there is no explanation at all.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

This may not match this specific problem, but I'll add this as something to check for others in case Google directs them here like it did for me.

In my case, I was getting a lot of errors like, "error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Client' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Xrm'".

Adding the **"Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions" NuGet package** fixed my compilation issues.

Answer (score 1):

After changing to .NET Framework 4 and changing .NET Framework into 3.5 and then back to 4.0, my poject was still not working.

It didn't work when I selected the option given by the "add Reference" window.

What worked for me was to click on the *browse* button in the "add Reference" window and look for the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.*dll* file

Answer (score 1):

I had .NET 4.0 as my target framework and I had this compiler error. I tried changing it back to 3.5 and then back to 4.0 and that didn't fix it.

What did fix the problem for me was deleting the bin, obj and tools folders in my project directory. I don't understand the details of why this worked, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and in my case, after trying all the above solutions and others on the web with no success, finally I came to a solution.

The problem was in the version of CRM SDK that I was using: 2015 (don´t wanna know why!).

Downloaded CRM 2013 SDK version, changed the assembly references to that version and the problem was gone.

Comment: Is it possible that the CRM 2015 version would work but that you had a different problem (that was eliminated by **something else** than getting back to 2013 **but invoked** by doing so)? Maybe you had wrong version of .NET framework referenced and when you went down to 2013 (which by itself didn't matter, you also **unknowingly** switched to the right version of .NET framework?

Comment: I tried .net versions 3 to 4.5 when I was trying to solve the problem. My time was running out for the project so I did not keep investigating the issue. This (use JDK 2013) is a walk arround advise for those whom didn't worked any other solution. Regards Konrad

Comment: Good suggestion, at any rate, anyway, so I gave it +1. Just to be a bit nit-picky: I don't think JDK 2013 helped. SDK 2013 did, right? JDK = Java Developer Kit, hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for it is CRM 2015 SDK was built on .Net 4.5.2 Framework and the Visual studio does not support 4.5.2.

Just download .Net Framework 4.5.2 
Goto Project Properties and change the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with my CRM 2011 Plugin. In my case none of the above solution worked.

In my code I am using early bound class. When generating this class file i was using following line along with other settings which was causing the error.

```
/codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization, Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration"
```

Once I added this new class file without codeCustomization, it removed all errors.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before,

> Reason for it is CRM 2015 SDK was built on .Net 4.5.2 Framework and
>   the Visual studio does not support 4.5.2.
>
> Just download .Net Framework 4.5.2 Goto Project Properties and change
>   the framework.

Alternate way could be to replace Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll with file from older CRM SDK. I use VS2010, and CRM 2011 SDK file solved all compiler errors.

P.S. Switching project to .NET 3.5 and back to 4.0 did not helped

Answer (score 0):

Updating NuGet Package helped me to solve the problem