# The type or namespace name 'Xrm' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: .net-4.0, dynamics-crm, xrm

I have cloned a project which uses XRM. But it shows some error. I have downloaded Microsoft.XRM SDK 2015 and referenced those dlls to the project. But it didn't solve the issue. Also, the .net framework, I have used is 4. When I tried to build my application, it showing some error like

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Xrm' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Is there anything, I want to add/download in my project in order to get a reference to Microsoft.XRM?
Also, I have tried the solution specified in the [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372524/cant-access-microsoft-xrm-namespace)

Answer (score 2):

Select Object Browser in Visual Studio by  CTRL+ALT+J. and paste the keyword xrm and see the namespaces there , if it show than add in your codebehind. otherwise you need to download and add the reference dll

Comment: Yes.I have added the references.But still it showing the same error message

Answer (score 1):

Switch to .net framework 4.5.2 if u working in below this.
And Install NuGet package - 
1. Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk
2. Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling
(This worked for me.)